# CodeIgniter Active Records - repeating a reusult from a select query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a `mails` table which is my main tables for manipulating mails. I also have `mails_sent` and `mails_dates` which has FK connecting them with `mails` and contain data as follows `mails_dates` - a single mail could have more than one date set for sending so I have realtion `1:N` where `N` are all the dates set from the user for the mail to be send and `mails_sent` - after a mail is sent a new record is added in this table with the `id` of the mail and the date it was sent. Because as I mentioned a mail could be sent more than once here the relation is also `1:N` where `N` here represents the different dates when a mail was sent.

I need to show this info in a UI. First I had to show only the sending dates and I user this:

```
$this->db->select("mails.id, mails.subject, mails.dt_created, mails.groups");
        $this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( mails_dates.dt_sending_date, '%d-%m-%Y')) AS sending_dates", FALSE );
        $this->db->join('mails_dates','mails_dates.mail_id = mails.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('mails_sent','mails_sent.mail_id = mails.id', 'left');


        $this->db->from('mails');
        $this->db->group_by('mails.id');
        $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();

        return $res;
```

When I was using this everything was fine I was getting a string with all the dates in it. But the problem is when I try to get the dates when a mail was sent. I added one more select:

```
$this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( mails_sent.dt_sent, '%d-%m-%Y')) AS sent_dates", FALSE );
```

making my query looks like this:

```
    $this->db->select("mails.id, mails.subject, mails.dt_created, mails.groups");
    $this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( mails_sent.dt_sent, '%d-%m-%Y')) AS sent_dates", FALSE );
    $this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( mails_dates.dt_sending_date, '%d-%m-%Y')) AS sending_dates", FALSE );
    $this->db->join('mails_dates','mails_dates.mail_id = mails.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('mails_sent','mails_sent.mail_id = mails.id', 'left');

    $this->db->from('mails');
    $this->db->group_by('mails.id');
    $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $res;
```

But the problem is that If `sending_dates` contains let's say - 6 values, and `sent_dates` has only one I end up with a string containing 6 times the value of `sent_dates`. This is in production so I don't have a lot of records but the same happens with a query where I have 2 `sending_dates` and 1 record for `sent_dates` still I get 2 times the record from `sent_dates`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Make the `mails_sent` an inner JOIN.

Comment: No, this way I don't get all results as well. I saw a similar problem solved with using of distinct, but I tried a few things and still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, here it is:

```
$this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(mails_sent.dt_sent, '%d-%m-%Y'))) AS sent_dates", FALSE );
```

In other words just use `DISTINCT`.